# How to draw nodes at different "levels" in dot?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I would like to draw the following graph in dot:

[image: dot example]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rank=same;` to force this layout:

```
digraph example {
A -> B -> C -> D -> E;
{ rank = same {A, C, E}}
{ rank = same {B,D}}
}
```

Output:

[image: output]